# meaning of "little low"

Tags: subcontinental-english

This is the conversation in the book "Revolution 2020"

> Hey How are you?
>
> I am little low. she said

what is the meaning of little low. it means she is unhappy  ?

Comment: Yes, that is what it means. :) Have you seen our sister site, [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/)? It is helpful for basic questions such as this one. Please take the [tour](http://ell.stackexchange.com/tour) to see if it might be a better fit. Thanks.

Comment: “I am little low” does not make sense in English. Not does the punctuation you have used. If you are quoting from a book, please make sure that you quote it exactly.

Comment: [little](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/little?q=a+little#little__15), [low](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/low?q=low#low__24). As your extract stands, it's not grammatical. If you have mistyped it, please correct it. *Little* and *low* have their usual meenings as I have linked to above.

Comment: The book he is referring to is written by a B grade author called Chetan Bhagat. He has not made any typos. The books by CB are shit.

Answer (score 1):

"Little low" might not directly translate to "unhappy". It could mean things like a weaker state of mind, bad energy level leading to a low resolve to do things, low self esteem, or any combination of the aforementioned characteristics. A person not "up to his/her game" could say that he/she is a "little low". That phrase can have any number of uses. 
1. A programmer at work and down with cold could say that. He probably means that he cannot function at a 100%. 
2. A chess player out of practice could say that before a game. He means that he might not play as well as he normally does. 
3. Some one who has lost a sibling could say that. In which case they are probably just referring to their state of mind.

So, as you see, there can be a myriad of ways of interpreting that phrase. 
You have to judge the context appropriately.

Comment: The answer is probably a bit easier than you have implied. Every word must be assessed in its context. It does not mean answers are not possible. *A little low* can quite readily be understood as *a little sad*, *a little down*, *down in the dumps*, etc. If you need more context to answer the question, it is easy enough to ask the OP for more context.

Comment: I concur. But can't we answer someone's question by teaching them the right way to ask the question itself. That is what I was going for. If the OP knew how important "context" was, I suspect he/she might have already provided it. Thus, I felt it would be a good idea to first introduce the *idea* of a context through examples and then point to necessity of it. The OP is now equipped to answer his own question. Although I think the answer is better off left as a comment to the question.